# Yeoman tell Sass to generate css files

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, yeoman

I have generated an Angularjs project without Sass and with bootstrap.
Later on, I figured out I need Sass for directional css (ltr & rtl).
So I tried installing Sass in my project (I don't know if I did it right)

What I did :

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-sass
```

then

```
sudo npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev
```

I created a folder sass into app folder

Then I modified the grunt.js file :
I added this line to create a sass task :

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/sass',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            ext: '.css'
          }]
        }
      },
..//
```

then added this

```
  watch: {
    styles: {
      files: ['<%= config.app %>/sass/{,*/}*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass', 'newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
    }
    // ...
  }
```

Then this

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
 'clean:dist',
 'useminPrepare',
 'sass',
 // ...
]);
```

to run the task on build
What I expect when I run grunt serve :

The folder app/styles is populated with css from the scss files.
what I get : and empty folder.

Can you help please ?

Comment: Have you set up a serve task?

Comment: no but isn't it a core task ?

Comment: What happens if you try `grunt sass`?